# Do not empty clipboard on save

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

Excel removes clipboard contents every time I save the document. Is there a setting to disable this "feature"?

Comment: The default behavior is that Excel asks if you want to empty the clipboard.

Comment: I don't know... Perhaps it asked me months ago and I selected "Do not ask again" or something like that :-? I can't remember.

Comment: @Ramhound: The default behavior is that if you copied stuff *from* Excel, it will ask you *when closing the document*. Sadly, Excel also loves to delete third-party clipboard content in certain situations, e.g. I think when starting it and/or opening a spreadsheet. I doubt there is a way to disable that; at least I know of none.

Comment: @JanSchejbal - I have never had my clipboard content wiped out because I closed Excel.